# Get all documents of having unique value with elastic

Tags: elasticsearch

for example:
i have many documents like this:

```
email status
1@123.com open
1@123.com click
2@123.com open
3@123.com open
```

i will query all documents with unique status value :"open", due to the record "1@123.com" contains "click" status, so "1@123.com" don't expect!

i tried this below,but not my expect:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "hard_bounce_count": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "actionStatus": "open"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "email_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "email"
          }
        }
      }
```

my expect response like this:

```
2@123.com open
3@123.com open
```

How can i do this,thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, outer term-aggs (named **EMAIL_LIST**) return all emails and then within each email bucket, first it finds whether the status is open or not (using filter-aggs with name **OPEN**) then it finds if the status is other than "open" (using another filter-aggs with name **OTHER_THAN_OPEN**)

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "EMAIL_LIST": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "email.keyword"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "OPEN": {
               "filter": {
                  "bool": {
                     "must": [
                        {
                           "term": {
                              "status": "open"
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            },
            "OTHER_THAN_OPEN": {
               "filter": {
                  "bool": {
                     "must_not": [
                        {
                           "term": {
                              "status": "open"
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            },
            "SELECTION_SCRIPT": {
               "bucket_selector": {
                  "buckets_path": {
                     "open_count": "OPEN._count",
                     "other_than_open_count": "OTHER_THAN_OPEN._count"
                  },
                  "script": "params.other_than_open_count==0 && params.open_count>0"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Above "bucket_selector" aggregation select only those bucket to output which have only **open** status

```
 "aggregations": {
      "EMAIL_LIST": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "2@123.com",
               "doc_count": 1,
               "OTHER_THAN_OPEN": {
                  "doc_count": 0
               },
               "OPEN": {
                  "doc_count": 1
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "3@123.com",
               "doc_count": 1,
               "OTHER_THAN_OPEN": {
                  "doc_count": 0
               },
               "OPEN": {
                  "doc_count": 1
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

so final answer will be email *"2@123.com"* and *"3@123.com"*

Comment: in fact, i tried this script, but "must_not" conditions  is equals "must" conditions， it return "1@123.com" eventually

Comment: @steven  ok let me try some other solution

Comment: @steven one other solution: instead of putting separate document for any new Status if you append in the old one then your problem will be solved using simple query
**doc1: **{"email":"1@123.com","status":["open","click"]}
**doc2: **{"email":"2@123.com","status":["open"]}
**doc3: **{"email":"3@123.com","status":["open"]}

Comment: aha ,in fact, i can't change this data struct, thks!!

Comment: thks @torzonhot, i tried the similar script like this, but hao can i  show result exclude "1@email" in buckets.

Comment: I have gone through some documentation and find a final answer, so this problem can be solved using a new aggregation "bucket-selector-aggregation" 
[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html]
So i am updating my answer.

Comment: the answer you  last update can be solved my problem ,tks @torzonhot!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I can query this too.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "email": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "email"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "status_group": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "status"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

response:

```
"aggregations": {
    "email": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [{
                "key": "1@123.com",
                "doc_count": 2,
                "status_group": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [{
                            "key": "click",
                            "doc_count": 1
                        }, {
                            "key": "open",
                            "doc_count": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }, {
                "key": "2@123.com",
                "doc_count": 1,
                "status_group": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [{
                            "key": "open",
                            "doc_count": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }, {
                "key": "3@123.com",
                "doc_count": 1,
                "status_group": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [{
                            "key": "open",
                            "doc_count": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

but how can I exclude "1@email" in resulting buckets, Because I eventually need the statistics of all eligible documents